# Is the namespace created when free variables are used?

Tags: python, list, namespaces

```
x = 2
def my_func():
    print(x)
    print(dir())

my_func()
```

The output by the statement `print(dir())` is an empty list `[]`. Was the local namespace created but didn't contain any name or it wasn't created at all?

Comment: It was created by was empty since there are no local variables in your function.

Comment: @Tom Karzes Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` is part of the global in your case you can check it by

```
x = 2
def my_func():
    print(x)
    print(locals())
    print(globals())

my_func()
```

The `print(locals())` 
Output

```
{}
```

and the `print(globals())`
Output

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x004FC230>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'C:/Users/leeron.arad/Documents/test-proj/venv/t.py', '__cached__': None, 'x': 2, 'my_func': <function my_func at 0x0058E978>}
```

In the globals dict you can see the `'x': 2` that get printed in the `my_func` scope. 
The `x` values is not created in the function it's only from the global scope.

Comment: I don't feel that it answers my question: *"Was the local namespace created but didn't contain any name or it wasn't created at all?"*

Comment: Any function has a local namespace locals dict. when you defining params/variables they are adding to this dict function can't be without it.

Comment: Now you gave the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass any args inside `dir()`, like:

```
x = 2
def my_func():
    print(x)
    print(dir(1))

my_func()
```

Run this file and you might get the answer like this:

```
2
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'as_integer_ratio', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
```